# Proof of convergence and determination of the limit for a series, with a nested sum.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I happend to proof quite a few series convergent, however, this one is driving me nuts:

**My Task:**  Show that the following series converges, and determine its limit.

$$\sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty{}\sum_{\mu = 0}^\nu{}\binom{\nu}{\mu}\frac{1}{2^{\mu+\nu}}$$

**Solving Attempts:** I find the quotient criteria hard to apply here, and it did not lead me to something useful so far. Then i thought of the following: The series:

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty{}\binom{x}{n}$$  converges, that might be of some use.. for the majorant criterion maybe? But does it even make sense to apply that here? For the start i have to prove that the second sum convergence against 0, that is a necessary criterion for the convergence of the whole thing. Well i also know that:

$$\binom{n}{k}= \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$

Hmm, for what could i use that. The idea how to prove it just doesn't come to my mind.. As for the determination of the limit: I have no idea. I am sorry.

Any light you can shed on this is much appreciated.

P.S: Please note that i am studying analysis in first term.

Comment: not even a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ (\frac{3}{2})^n = (1+\frac{1}{2})^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{{n}\choose{k}} (\frac{1}{2})^k 1^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n{{n}\choose{k}} \frac{1}{2^k} $

$ \implies U_n = \sum_{k=0}^n{{n}\choose{k}} \frac{1}{2^{k+n}} = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n{{n}\choose{k}} \frac{1}{2^{k}} = \frac{3^n}{2^n2^n} = (\frac{3}{4})^n $

$\sum U_n$ exists since it's a geometric series, and you get :

$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} U_n = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}} \frac{1}{2^{k+n}} =\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (\frac{3}{4})^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{4}} = 4$

Comment: Sorry if I gave the answer completely, but the hint is the same as the complete solution..

Comment: The geometric series! Thank you.